# DynamoDB: Why shouldn't I introduce a premature sort key?

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

My application intends to store a list of items in a DynamoDB table. The chosen
partition key is each item's unique GUID, which supports all the access patterns
the app needs today.

| PK | item_name |
| --- | --- |
| c2401dc9-7e6f-4bd5-93bf-b2643314c3b4 | item number 1 |
| 00157505-7a9e-488a-83dd-602da786c9ac | item number 2 |
| 0342a419-3fed-4284-babd-5dfc3748e6ab | item number 3 |

Certainly, today just having a partition key on the table suffices. But I wonder
why wouldn't I want to add a sort key just in case my access patterns evolve?
Obviously, DynamoDB doesn't allow changing the keys of an existing table in the
future.

This is how I'm tempted to store my data instead:

| PK | SK | item_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c2401dc9-7e6f-4bd5-93bf-b2643314c3b4 | detail | item number 1 |
| 00157505-7a9e-488a-83dd-602da786c9ac | detail | item number 2 |
| 0342a419-3fed-4284-babd-5dfc3748e6ab | detail | item number 3 |

Tomorrow if my app needs more complicated access patterns, my hands would be
open to start introducing new sort keys. For example a versioning system:

| PK | SK | item_name | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c2401dc9-7e6f-4bd5-93bf-b2643314c3b4 | detail | item number 1 |  |
| 00157505-7a9e-488a-83dd-602da786c9ac | detail | item number 2 |  |
| 0342a419-3fed-4284-babd-5dfc3748e6ab | detail | item number 3 |  |
| ea2b656a-5fb2-483f-8ad8-59d3f82605ab | detail | item number 4 |  |
| ea2b656a-5fb2-483f-8ad8-59d3f82605ab | version#1 | Item number 4 |  |
| ea2b656a-5fb2-483f-8ad8-59d3f82605ab | version#2 | Item Number 4 |  |
| ea2b656a-5fb2-483f-8ad8-59d3f82605ab | version#3 | ItemNumber 4 |  |
| ea2b656a-5fb2-483f-8ad8-59d3f82605ab | version |  | 3 |

In my head, the latter is an obvious winner. I don't see why I wouldn't want to
have a sort key even if my app ends up never needing it at all. What's the harm
anyway?

Could you please enlighten me if there's an associated cost I'm not aware of and
why I should stick with the former approach?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you cannot alter a primary key after the table has already been created. There is no real downsides for having a sort-key which you do not require, just to future proof your table, except for the storage and throughput costs associated with the additional bytes.

From your description it adds 8-10 bytes to your item. Made up over your entire dataset, millions or billions of items it may add up in storage costs, potentially. But its trivial.

From a throughput perspective, adding 8-10 bytes may increase your item size and push it into the next range of costs. For example, if you had an item that was 1040 bytes and you added 10 bytes, you've increased your item size from being charged 1WCU per update, to 2WCU, doubling your write costs. Again, trivial but something to look out for.

But as I said in the beginning, there is no real downside.